# unable to patchValue to formArray in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am new to angular, I simply want to patch value to my formArray.

Here is my code. I have tried but it's not working:

**home.html**

```
<ion-list formArrayName="belt_array">
        <div *ngFor="let obj of form.controls.belt_array.controls;let i=index">
            <ion-row [formGroupName]="i">
                <ion-col class="pl-0">
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="data"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
```

**home.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.formParamsForm = this._fb.group({
      belt_array: this._fb.array([], Validators.minLength(1))
   });
}

loadData(){
      this.formParamsForm.setControl('belt_array', this._fb.array(myArr));
}
```

myArr = [
{
"data": "a1"
},
{
"data": "a2"
},
{
"data": "a3"
}
];

Onclick of the button I am calling loadData() but my app doesn't load data of myArr.

*Where is my mistake, can anyone help me?*

***Thank you in advance!***

Answer (score 0):

Since myArr is array of object we need to create array of formGroup.

```
 const arrOfFormGroup =  myArr.map(arr=>(this.fb.group({data:arr.data})));
```

When we use setControl method we should call [updateValueAndValidity](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity). to update the value and validity of formGroup

```
loadData(){
  this.formParamsForm.setControl('belt_array', this._fb.array(arrOfFormGroup)); 
  this.formParamsForm.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

OR

We could use formArray [push](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#push) method to insert new control to formArray instead of setMethod.

```
loadData(){ 
     arrOfFormGroup.forEach(arr=>{
       (this.formParamsForm.get('belt_array') as FormArray).push(arr);
      });               
}
```